# Ajax code for calling Cloudify Rest API responds with error "undefined"

Tags: jquery, ajax, cloudify, rest

I am trying to call a REST API post method to Cloudify.

I can run this successfully from commandline. Please see the command.

```
curl -X POST --header "Tenant: default_tenant" --header "Content-Type: application/json" -u admin:admin -d '{"deployment_id": "OSCreateVM", "workflow_id": "install"}' "http://xxxxxxxxx/api/v3.1/executions?_include=id"
```

However when I create an AJAX REST API call from my html, I am getting an "undefined" error. What went wrong here? Can someone help please?

```
function ajaxFunction(){
var parameters= {"deployment_id": "OSCreateVM", "workflow_id": "install"};
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://xxxxxxxxx/api/v3.1/executions?_include=id",
        headers: {
        'Tenant': 'default_tenant',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        data: JSON.stringify(parameters),
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "json",
        username: "admin",
        password: "admin",
        success: function (responseData, status, jqXHR) {
            alert ("Request for VM Creation is Succcessfully submitted");
         },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
             // error handler
             alert(request.responseText);
         }
      });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand what went wrong, syntactically it looks valid but "undefined" could be a lot of things.

I suggest you try to look at the events in the Cloudify manager Web-UI or CLI to understand what was undefined. 
If you use the Web-UI go to the deployments tab, look for OSCreateVM, click on it and look at the executions done to see more details.

If you do it via CLI run `cfy executions list -d OSCreateVM`

Once you have the executions list run `cfy events list <ID_OF_THE_INSTALL_EXECUTION`

Answer (score 0):

I tested more. Undefined Error occurs because of this line: "alert(request.responseText);",
request object doesn't have a responseText variable defined in it.

If you change the code as below, undefined error will disappear.

```
error: function (request) {
             // error handler
             alert(request.status);
         }
```